# MediaPlayer issue in most android 6.0 devices in streaming

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

In android 6.0 devices (not emulators api 23) I am receiving weird problem. Player starts playing song but after 1 or 2 seconds it again goes to 00:00 during this transition player skips the time required for transition and starts playing from that place eg(00:07).

But after 20+ seconds song starts playing normally for about 5 to 10 seconds and then player stops playing because the song is completed. Total time of this process is half than the duration of song.

What I think is there must be problem in preparing the music, but I am not sure what is the problem.

Here is the code what I have written so far

```
 public static MediaPlayer player = null;
 // above line is declared at start of class

// below code is written in a async task doInBackground
 if (player != null) {
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
    durationOfSong = 0;
    String streamUrl = getSongsList.getStreamUrl(position);
    player = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(streamUrl));
    try {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "end time: " + player.getDuration());
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSong, 100);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                loadingSongProgress.setMessage("Buffering song...");
            }
        });
        Manipulate manipulate = new Manipulate();
        endTimingOfSong = manipulate.MillisecondsToFormat(player.getDuration());

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "NP: error: " + e.toString());
        DialogWithNoSongError(view);
    }

 // and in post execute method
 loadingSongProgress.dismiss();
 player.start();
 createMediaDialog(view,position);
 // create media dialog is used to show image, song name and running time
```

Android devices running <6.0 OS and emulators (running 6.0) plays song in normal fashion.
If more code is needed I will edit the post, in case needed please suggest.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is your streamUrl an VimeoURL?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the code the following code from the bottom

> player.start();

and replace the following

```
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    loadingSongProgress.setMessage("Buffering song...");
                      mHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSong, 100)
                }
            });
player.prepareAsync();
```

Try to run this it might help you

Comment: No changes same thing appears!!

Comment: In your code, You are starting the player without checking whether the media player is ready to play or not. So You have to start the runnable inside onPrepared which will make media player to play smoothly.

Comment: Nope handler is called only once if I put handler in onprepared method.

Comment: You can either do a call to player.prepareAsync(); to change the song or create a flag to identify whether onPrepared is already invoked - So that you can call handler directly without onPrepared

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
player.setDataSource(getSongsList.getStreamUrl(position)); 
player.prepareAsync();
```

Note: There are two methods to prepare the media player:
1. player.prepare(); this one returns after completing the prepare operation hence causes a delay in the UI thread.

2. prepare.prepareAsync(); this one does all that works asynchronously. Hence does not cause any delay in UI thread.